# EDIT variational formulation-exercice

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

i have this problem.
Let $\Omega$ a bounded domain, connexe and regular, and let $f \in L^2(\Omega).$ Let the variational problem: Find $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ such 
$$\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \nabla v dx + (\int_{\Omega} u dx)(\int_{\Omega} v dx) = \int_{\Omega} f v dx, \forall v \in H^1(\Omega)$$
Deduce the boundary problem associate to this variational problem ( study the two cases $u \in  H^2(\Omega)$ and $u \notin H^2(\Omega)$.

in the case 1: $u\in H^2(\Omega)$

In this case, we have that $$\tag{1}\int_\Omega \nabla u\nabla v=-\int_\Omega v\Delta u+\int_{\partial\Omega}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}v,\ \forall\ v\in H^1(\Omega)$$

From $(1)$, we conclude that $$\tag{2}-\int_\Omega v\Delta u+\int_{\partial\Omega}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}v+\int_\Omega (\int_\Omega u)v=\int f v,\ \forall\ v\in H^1(\Omega)$$

If we take $v\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ in $(2)$, we can conclude by the Fundamental Lemma of Calculus of Variation that $$\tag{3}-\Delta u(x)+\int_\Omega u=f(x),\ a.e.\ x\in\Omega$$

My question is: how we use the Fundametal Lemme Of Calculus Of Variation to deduce this?
and why we choose $v\in C^{\infty} (\Omega)$? why we can't work with $v \in H^1(\Omega)$?

My second question is: we put $$a(u,v)=\int_{\Omega}A \nabla u \cdot \nabla v dx + (\int_{\Omega} udx)(\int_{\Omega}vdx), \forall v \in H^1(\Omega)$$
How we prouve that $a$ is coercitive.
for this, i process by absurde, so we have to prouve that $$\forall v \in V, \exists \nu > 0; a(v,v)< \nu ||v||^2_V$$
we choise $\nu=\dfrac{1}{n}$ , so we have $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists v \in H^1(\Omega):a(v_n,v_n)<\dfrac{1}{n}||v_n||^2_V$$
I don't understand how we use the Rellich theorem to conclude the coercitivity.

Comment: who can help me please

Comment: Problably you have asked this question here like 3 or 4 times.

Comment: yes, i know it but i don't understand the steps where we use the fundamental lemma of calculus of variation. How we apply this lemma in my problem please

Comment: Do you know what is the fundamental lemma?

Comment: i know it but i don't understand how we can use it, it's been weeks since I tried but I do not understand

Comment: So please, state here the fundamental lemma to me and explain to me, how did you tried to use it

Comment: The fundamental lemma says:let $f \in C^k([a,b]).$ Assume that $\int_a^b f(x) h(x) dx = 0,\forall h \in C^k(a,b)$ with $h(a)=h(b)=0.$ Then, the fundamental lemma states that $f(x)$ is identicallyzero on $[a,b].$

Comment: In this exercice, we have that $-\int_{\Omega} v \Delta u+\int_{\partial \Omega} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} v+\int_{\Omega}(\int_{\Omega}u)v=\int_{\Omega}fv,\forall v \in C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$ we hav any assuption to applie the fundamental lemma and conclude that $\Delta u+\int_{\Omega}u=f$p.p in $\Omega$.

Comment: It does work for functions in $\mathbb{R}^N$ too and also it can be refined to the space $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$. Do you knew it?

Comment: yes, but what's the relation wuith the fundamental lemma?

Comment: In fact, it can be stated in a more general form: Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be an open set and let $u\in L^1_{loc} (\Omega)$ be such that $$\int_\Omega uf=0,\ \forall\ f\in C_c^\infty (\Omega)$$ Then $u=0$ a.e. in $\Omega$. Do you knew it? It is a generalization of the fundamental lemma. This statement can be found in Brezi's book of functional analysis chapter 4.

Comment: if we havejust $\int_{\Omega} (-\Delta u +\int_{\Omega} u - f)vdx= 0$, so by fundamental lemma we conclude that $-\Delta u + \int_{\Omega} u - f(x)=0$p.p. but we have $\int_{\partial \Omega} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} v$ in the formula. So 
how it disappears?

Comment: Your are taking $v\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$, hence, $v=0$ in the boundary, which implies that the integral "in the boundary" is zero.

Comment: Okay! Thank you so much. I have an other question please, i edit my first post.

Comment: I alread proved it in another post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434702/variational-problem-exercice/434756#434756

Comment: yes, but i don't understand how we use the rellich theorem here? and in the proof by absurde, we have existence of $v$ don't for all v. so why we can choose $||v||=1?$ help me please in this two points.

Comment: Can you help me please

Comment: It is your proof, how can you not undertand it? I just corrected the end of the proof, which was wrong.

Comment: yes, I read the beginning of the proof of a book, but when I returned I just realized that I did not understand the use of Rellich theorem. Can you help me make a clear proof of the coercivity? please this is a big problem for me

Comment: Talk to me in the post where the answer is, the post I have linked here. Write there what are your doubts and I will try to help you.

Comment: I posted my questin where the answer is. Help me please to understand