# convergence exercice

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

I have a question please, thanks to help me.
Let $\Omega$ an open bounded, connexe and regular
Let $(v_n)$ an sequence in $H^1(\Omega)$ and let $v \in H^1(\Omega)$ such that $v_n$ converge weakly in $L^2(\Omega)$ to $v$.
How we can compute the limits $$\int_{\Omega} A |\nabla v_n|^2 dx$$ and $$\int_{\Omega} v_n dx$$ when $n$ tends to $+\infty$

($A$ is such that $\exists \alpha > 0, A(x) \xi \xi \geq \alpha |\xi|^2, \forall \xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\exists \beta > 0, |A(x) \xi| \leq \beta |\xi|, \forall \xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$)
Thanks for the help.

Comment: The first expression does not seem well-defined: $A$ is apparently a matrix from your footnote, but you have written it as acting on a scalar. Do you mean $|A \nabla v_n|^2$?

Comment: the first expression is $$\int_{\Omega} A \nabla v \cdot \nabla v dx$$there is a problem in this expression?

Comment: That makes more sense - you should be interpreting it as $(A \nabla v) \cdot \nabla v$, since the other grouping makes no sense!

Comment: ok, so how we compute $$\lim_n \int_{\Omega} (A \nabla v_n) \cdot \nabla v_n dx$$?

Comment: I don't think you have sufficient information to determine whether or not that converges - in particular the weak $L^2(\Omega)$ convergence tells you nothing about the behaviour of $\nabla v_n$. Consider $\Omega = (0,2 \pi)$, $v_n(x) = \sin (n x)$ and $A$ the identity; then $v_n \rightharpoonup 0$ weakly in $L^2$ but $\int A \nabla v_n \cdot \nabla v_n dx = n^2 \pi$ does not converge.

Comment: we can prouve that $$\lim_n \int_{\Omega} (A \nabla v_n) \cdot \nabla v_n dx = \int_{\Omega} (A \nabla v) \cdot \nabla v dx$$?

Comment: No, I just gave a counterexample to that.

Comment: So how we can resolve this question? plkease. We have $a(v,v)=\int_{\Omega} (A \nabla v)\cdot \nabla v dx + (\int_{\Omega} v dx)^2$ and we have to prouve that $a$ is coercive.By absurde, we suppose that $a$ isn't coercive, so $$\forall \nu > 0, \exists v \in H^1(\Omega); a(v,v)<\nu ||v||^2_{H^1(\Omega)}$$ in particular, with $\nu=\dfrac{1}{n}$, and we can take $v_n$ such that $||v_n||_{H^1}=1$, we have $a(v_n,v_n)<\dfrac{1}{n}$ so how we can passe to the limit in $a(v_n,v_n)$ when $n$ tends to $+\infty$?

Comment: help me please, it's been weeks since I seek the answer to this question

Comment: what's the problem of this question please

Comment: Your $v_n$ is bounded in $H^1$, so you can extract a subsequence that is weakly convergent in $H^1$, not just in $L^2$. This stronger convergence will give you the convergence of the first integral.

Comment: what's the name of the theorem who gives the weakly convergence in $L^2(\Omega)$? and, for the justificaion of the limit, we have $v_n$ converge weakly in $H^1$ to $v,$ if anb only if $v_n$ converge weakly in $L^2$ to $v$ and $\nabla v_n$ converge weakly in $L^2$ to $\nabla v$, then $\lim_n \int_{\Omega} (A \nabla v_n) \varphi dx=\int_{\Omega} (A \nabla v) \varphi dx$ forall \varphi \in L^2,$ but, i don't know how we justifie rigourously that $$\lim_n \int (A \nabla v_n)\cdot \nabla v_n dx = \int (A \nabla v) \cdot \nabla v) dx$$ can you help me please

Comment: can you help me please

Comment: You're right that the weak convergence is not enough for that integral to converge - in general it requires strong convergence. Anyway a proof of coercivity for such a simple functional is usually not so involved... have you tried a direct estimate bounding $a(v,v)$ from below in terms of $\Vert v \Vert_{H^1}$? The only real work is finding the right inequality to handle the $(\int v)^2$...

Comment: but there isn't an equality to estimate $(\int v)^2$ with $||v||_{H^1}$ and you tell me that the weakly convergence in $H^1$ can give the convergence of $\int (A \nabla v_n)\cdot \nabla v_n dx$ to $\int (A \nabla v)\cdot \nabla v dx$ . i am lost.

Comment: I was mistaken - for example when $A$ is the identity that convergence is convergence of the $H^1$ norm itself which together with weak convergence is equivalent to strong convergence. Are you sure that functional is really coercive? Perhaps try to construct a counterexample if you believe the $(\int v)^2$ cannot be estimated (I certainly couldn't do it with a quick try)

Comment: yes she is coercitive, and we prouve this by absurde. my difficulties is to passe to the limit in $\int A \nabla v_n ) \cdot \nabla v_n dx$ can you help me? i

Comment: I've asked the question      http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434702/variational-problem-exercice/434756#434756   but I have not understand the last step to found the limit of $\int (A \nabla v_n)\cdot \nabla v_n dx$ can you help me please

Comment: help me please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit of the second sequence should be obvious from the definition of weak convergence once you notice that $$ \int_\Omega v_n dx = (v_n, 1)_{L^2(\Omega)}$$ where $1$ is the constant function on $\Omega$ with value 1.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Omega = (-\pi,\pi)$. Let $v_n(x) = \dfrac{\sin(n^2x)}{n}$. Let $A\xi = \xi$. It is clear that $v_n \rightharpoonup 0$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, since in fact $v_n$ converges uniformly. Now, $\nabla v_n(x) = n\cos(n^2 x)$ and thus $(A\nabla v_n) \cdot \nabla v_n = n^2 \cos^2(n^2 x)$. You get $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi (A\nabla v_n) \cdot \nabla v_n \, dx = \int_{-\pi}^\pi n^2\cos^2(n^2 x) \, dx = n^2 \pi$$ for all $n$. In this case the limit is infinite. You can modify this example in a trivial way to get a finite limit or a zero limit, or even a divergent sequence.

Comment: any one can help me please